# O certo é passar "COMO" ou "POR" argumento?

Tags: português-brasileiro, preposições

Em **linguagens de programação**, palavras como ***como*** e ***por***, ao se referenciar as passagens de argumentos, são muito utilizadas. Contudo, ao questionar alguns *programadores*, os mesmos não sabem explicar a diferença entre o uso das palavras e dizem que "tecnicamente" não há. Sendo assim, na **língua portuguesa**, qual seria a maneira mais coerente ao se falar sobre *[passagem de argumentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32450/31236)*?

Comment: Luccas, não queres, para benefício dos poucos aqui na comunidade que não entendem muito de computação (eu :( por exemplo), incluir  frases que exemplifiquem esse uso de *como* e *por?* Reformatei algumas coisas na pergunta, seguindo princípios correntemente usados: negrito para ênfase, itálico para mencionar a palavra (por oposição a usá-la); aspas no título, que não aceita itálico.  É a tua pergunta, se não gostares, faz rollback. Fiz outras correções menores. "Referenciar **à** passagens" não podia ser; hesitei entre *a* (preposição) ou *as*; com *referenciar* parece-me melhor *as*. Vê lá.

Comment: passar dados através, via : "Os dados dessa função vão passar por parâmetro" ; Definir os dados que vou usar "Vou usar como parâmetro esses dados".

Comment: @Jacinto a comunidade técnica precisa de revisores não-técnicos que dominem de fato a língua portuguesa. Ocorre de muitas documentações virem erradas por serem feitas por programadores e não entendedores de língua portuguesa. Pode ocorrer de tais termos se alastrarem como vírus mesmo que errados.

Comment: Esta observação fica só como comentário, já que a pergunta contém a tag português-brasileiro: em Portugal usa-se "passar por"; fazendo uma rápida *google battle* por "passar como referência", restringida ao domínio `.pt`, devolve apenas 2 hits, enquanto que no outro caso devolve >6000. Retirando a restrição do domínio, o número de hits é semelhante nos dois casos.

Comment: Eu evitaria o uso de como ou por. Nao vejo nenhuma razao para os usar. `A função foi chamada com os argumentos x e y`.
`A função tem os parâmetros x e y`. `Os argumentos X e Y foram passados á funcao`.
`Foi atribuido o valor Z ao parametro X da funcao`.
`A funcao recebeu o valor Z no parametro X`.
`O valor Z foi passado no parametro X da funcao`.

Comment: Olá @Jacinto, obrigado pelas correções. Contudo, insisto em ficar com a crase em: "às passagens de argumentos", tendo em vista que _passagem de argumentos_ é uma etapa/característica das linguagens de programação.

Comment: Luccas, tudo bem. O que estava no original era ***à** passagens* e não ***às*** (podes confirmar no historial da edição), que não podia ser. De qualquer maneira "*ao se referenciar às passagens de argumentos*" não está bem (*referenciar* é transitivo direto, e não se aplica ao contexto). Está bem é como dizes no  fim da pergunta, "*ao se falar de passagem de argumentos*" (ou "*ao nos referirmos a passagem de argumentos*").

Comment: Certo, realmente me equivoquei, vou realizar a edição e obrigado novamente.

Comment: @BrunoCosta isso não responde à pergunta. O contexto nesses exemplos não é o mesmo que na pergunta. Em Inglês, *pass by reference* e *pass by value* referem-se a modos diferentes de passar argumentos a funções, que não são capturados nos exemplos dados no teu comentário.

Comment: @iled A pergunta nao faz nenhuma referencia a "pass by reference" nem a "pass by value"

Comment: @BrunoCosta a pergunta faz menção ao contexto: *Em linguagens de programação, palavras como como e por, ao se **referenciar as passagens de argumentos*** (ênfase meu). Se entender do contexto, rapidamente vê a relação com o que referi. No entanto, concordo que a pergunta poderia estar mais elaborada e fornecer exemplos para os que não têm prática no contexto.

Comment: @iled, compreendi sua resposta nos comentários e ela se mostrou uma alternativa útil. Porém, tentei ser o mais específico possível no título da pergunta e não vi, sendo que o foco era o **português**, a necessidade de ter um conhecimento técnico aprofundado, o que me levou a colocar apenas uma referência para o que seria _passagem de parâmetros_.

Comment: @luccasrodrigo eu não dei nenhuma resposta... só estava a indicar que a *resposta* dada pelo Bruno (nos comentários) não é adequada. Eu acho que para responder à pergunta colocada é necessário saber em que contexto ocorre a dúvida do "como" ou "por". A pergunta pode ser melhorada se forem incluídos exemplos de frases onde a dúvida ocorre. [Ver exemplo na Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estratégia_de_avaliação#Chamada_por_valor).

Comment: Olá iled, perdão, fiz menção errada à você.O comentário era para o @BrunoCosta.

Comment: @iled, sobre os exemplos, tais contextos não se enquadrariam no meu caso, por isso a pergunta foi bem específica.

Answer (score 1):

Independente da forma do uso se é possível chegar no objetivo, as duas partes se entenderam, então não tem problema quaisquer for sua opção (por ou como) se for usado para comunicação oral. A ideia é não ser pedante.

No geral se usa *por* formalmente (vai escrever um artigo cientifico de programação, escrever uma documentação), seria o mais adequado:

> [**por**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/por)
>   *preposição*
>
> 1. Designativa de várias relações; modo: por força; causa: por doença; meio: por terra ou por água; tempo: por um ano, etc.

*A passagem de parâmetros por argumento padrão*, argumento padrão é o modo.

Exemplo de documentações:

[Passagem de parâmetros](http://www.inf.pucrs.br/manssour/LinguagemC++/PassagemParam.pdf)

[Passando argumentos por valor e por referência](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ddck1z30.aspx)

Na comunicação oral pode também se ouvir o *como*, dependendo da utilização é coerente com o contexto:

> [**como**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/como) *conjunção*
>
> 1. Do mesmo modo que.
> 2. Quando.
> 3. Logo que.
> 4. Visto que.
> 5. Se.
> 6. Uma vez que.
> 7. Segundo, conforme.
> 8. Indica a .perspectiva ou o estatuto de alguém em relação a algo (ex.: como cidadão, esta situação .me indigna). = ENQUANTO, NA QUALIDADE DE
> 9. De que modo?

*Poxa, não funcionou? Passa isso como argumento*, do mesmo modo que um argumento, em uma situação que o ideal fosse parâmetro, valor, referência ou o que você achar que estiver correto, menos o argumento.

Indiferente a palavra, foi o jeito que o programador achou na hora para se expressar.

Pode também significar indiferença por conta de uma luta infinita para saber qual termo é o *mais correto*.

Comment: A questão é o ponto de referência. Se é o programador, ele vai falar pro outro passar como argumento. Se é se referindo a função, então a função vai passar os dados por parâmetro que pode ser valor ou referência. Nem sempre você precisa estar falando de funções diretamente visíveis; podendo elas estarem transparentes ao usuário como em linhas de comando de prompt "Use como argumento/parâmetro para o programa /help".

Comment: Sim, mas como programador para programador, este pode falar "passar por argumento" que não teria problema. É verdade o que disse, mas tentei limitar a pergunta do OP sobre linguagem de programação não de software no geral.

Comment: Você pode estar programando um programa que recebe argumentos de linha de comando (mesmo no atalho do programa).

Answer (score 0):

Lucas,

O correto é passagem **por** argumento/parâmetro, pois o argumento/parâmetro é colocado no método e não é igual nem comparável ao método para se utilizar a expressão **como** argumento/parâmetro.

Quando se faz um método ser acessado se utiliza `setAtributo` e não `asAtributo`.

#### Por:

- por
- for, by, through, per

#### Como:

- how adv, as conj, like prep
- como adv

#### Colocar:

- set (place, locate)
- colocar, botar  (pôr, localizar)

#### Mais informações:

- http://www.wordreference.com/pten/por
- http://www.wordreference.com/pten/como
- http://www.wordreference.com/pten/colocar

Comment: Na programação há passagem por parâmetro e passagem por referência. Na passagem por valor, é passada uma cópia do valor da variável. Na passagem por referência, é passada uma referência à própria variável.

Comment: @AndréLyra isso são as variações da passagem de parâmetro na programação em si e você observar você utilizou a palavra "por" em ambos os casos. Já que objetivo da questão é a língua portuguesa e não as estratégias de programação fica claro que a expressão "como parâmetro" é um erro de linguagem e virou uma espécie de gíria para quem não conhece programação e português efetivamente.

Comment: Na linguagem de programação você passa os dados por valor ou por referência à variável; o que significaria na outra ponta receber o valor como uma variável pré existente ou como um valor atribuído naquele momento. A palavra Por é usada para indicar o meio de transporte ou de acesso aos dados.

Comment: A pergunta foi "o certo é PASSAR..." e não "o certo é RECEBER..." e como você disse: Na linguagem de programação você PASSA os dados POR valor ou POR referência e RECEBE COMO variável.

Comment: `O correto é passagem por parâmetro`Trocou a palavra ai. Devia ser passar por argumento e nao passar por parâmetro.

Comment: "Em C#, podem ser passados argumentos aos parâmetros por valor ou por referência."; "Para usarmos um método que recebe um inteiro como parâmetro precisamos passar um argumento ao método."; "instrução deve passar um "endereço" desse argumento para um parâmetro do tipo ponteiro." Argumento = "valor ou item"; Parâmetro = "campo ou o local onde coloca esse valor"

Comment: "e não é igual nem comparável ao método para se utilizar a expressão como parâmetro." isso não está compreensível, por isso meus comentários.